# Error DBML 1062 - no primary key

Tags: sql, linq

I'm using Linq to SQL and some of my tables don't have primary keys: this generates warnings. Is it a problem to have tables with no primary key?

Thanks.

Comment: Joe Celko said: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table!* Every "normal" table ought to have a primary key to uniquely identify each row of that table.

Comment: "If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table" - yep... it's a view, and should be perfectly fine to be queryable.  Kidding aside, I agree with you that tables without PKs are very very wrong, but that doesn't change the reality that sometimes that's just the way things are and if we can't change it then we have to work around it.  L2S will work fine in a select-only situation for these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only doing selects from your table, then technically no - there's no problem with there being no primary key.  But inserts, updates, and deletes will be problematic.  The only reason I've found to not have PKs in your DBML is when you're pointing at a view for readonly data access.  But tables really should always have an officially declared primary key constraint.